# Reduce Mouse Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple application using canvas but I require to lower down the speed of mouse-move when I take the mouse over the canvas. I tried finding the solution on internet but couldn't.

I just wanted to know if it is possible can anyone help please.

Comment: I think it's a browser indipendent feature and can't be modified; the speed and other features can be customized in client OS

Comment: I would certainly hope this is not possible. The potential for evil is too great.

Comment: The only way for you to do this would be to actually go and change the clients settings in their PC from control panel ( which obviously you can't do. ) ... that is to my knowledge , so this is why i posted as comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're working with a canvas, you're likely making a game - and I'd say this might be more possible than you think. You probably won't be able to use the actual mouse pointer itself - probably not an issue if you have some mouse graphic available - but could have a "virtual" mouse using this, taking MouseMove events and multiplying them by some fraction. Unfortunately, I think you'd have to do a lot of the research yourself!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Pointer_Lock

This API is used for things like the Quake WebGL demos.

(To those worried about security: Don't worry, the API has the browser request permission from the user using a dropdown)